# How to update a child component when data array inserting new elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue.js child component with a data array called `messages`. How to update the DOM when inserting new elements in the array.

here is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
<template>
  <q-item v-for="(msg, i) in messages" :key="i" >
    <!-- q-item is a custom component of quasar framework -->
    <!-- some code here related to msg -->
  </q-item>
<template/>

<script>
  export default {
  data () {
    return {
      messages: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage () {
      // submit the formData
      this.submitFormData({url: '/messages/new', formData})
        .then((message) => {
          this.messages.push(message)
        })
      },
    }
  }
}
<script/>
```

using the vue devtools I can see that the messages array is updated, but I can't ge the DOM updated according to it.

**note** that this is a child component, not the vue instance ($forceUpdate don't work)

Comment: Where's the template code?

Comment: Can you add the full component code? I think there's another problem in your code because Vuejs will auto rerender component if it's data changes

Comment: Try adding `console.log( this.messages )` after pushing a new message to this array. It should contain the newly added message. The problem might be in a different part of your code not displayed here.

Comment: I updated the question with template @Mjh

Comment: your `methods` object should not be in your `data` method. Currently your `return` statement in the `data` method is not valid javascript.

Comment: @thanksd this was just a typo when I moved the code from the editor to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you should do this:

```
<template>
    <q-item v-for="(msg, i) in messages" :key="i" >
    <!-- q-item is a custom component of quasar framework -->
    <!-- some code here related to msg -->
    </q-item>
<template/>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            messages: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitMessage () {
        // submit the formData
        this.submitFormData({url: '/messages/new', formData})
            .then((message) => {
            this.messages.push(message)
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

One of the best part of the vue is, that it dynamically update the gui elements (components), your mistake was that `methods: {}` was inside `data() {}`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @LakiGeri for your answer .. but the problem was not that, this was just a typo .. I have the array updated successfully and I can check that in the vue devtools as I said above but the view doesn't re-render

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issues with the code, this may be related to another part of the application.

I've tried adding the code as is, with the exception of having this within the return of a promise, and it seems to work ok.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyaao6ec/

```js
Vue.component('test', {
  template: `<div>
  <button @click="submitMessage('hi')">MESSAGE</button>
  <p v-for="(msg, i) in messages" :key="i" >{{msg}}
  </p>
</div>`
 ,data () {
    return {
      messages: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage (message) {
      this.messages.push(message)
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"><test></test></div>
```

can you try moving `this.messages.push(message)` out of the promise (and adding 
a some pre-defined string)?

Comment: thanx for the answer but that was the same .. I forgot to say that I am loading this component using vue-router .. it may be the source of the problem